# Build One Project from GIT Repo (Jenkins/GIT)

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-git-plugin

I am trying to check out just one maven project from  a GIT repo (Total of 49 modules) in Jenkins and do a build. The only reason is that they all need to be built a little bit differently in order to be deployed on to Tomcat. I probably might have been able to do it in SVN because I have dealt with it for a decade. But I am a spring chicken when it comes to GIT, I just don't have much idea how to get this to work. The current GIT folder structure is like:

```
    Maven Parent Project
        Child Project A
        Child Porject B
        Child Porject C
        Child Porject D
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        and so on...
```

Now lets say I want to create a job that just builds ChildProjectD, how do I go about it? Is it even possible? I did install the plugin GIT Parameter, thinking it would get me somewhere. But just don't know what to put in the fields.

Any help with this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These following guidelines may help you with initializing a Jenkins freestyle job for building a subproject rather than building all projects included in a git repo.

1. Install git-plugin for Jenkins
2. Create a freestyle job and add your git hub repository's link on SCM repository field

   - New Item -->
   - Name the item and OK -->
   - Select Git in SCM -->
   - Add repository URL -->
   - Add invoke top-level maven targets as Build steps -->
   - In Goals `install -pl ChildProjectD`
   - (optional) Add post-build and other configurations

It will build the Child project as you want instead of full project.
You can refer [Jenkins GitHub Java Application Project Build Configuration Maven](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Jenkins/Jenkins_GitHub_Java_Application_Project_Build_Configuration_Maven.php) to get more help. Check also `mvn install -pl --help` for more info.

Feel free to ask questions.